# How to run a program through Tor

Tags: ubuntu, tor, privacy

I want to run programs from my ubuntu machine through Tor, without TAILS. i was wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `tsocks` if you are looking for a way to "torify" any application.  You need to edit `/etc/tsocks.conf` to point to your instance of Tor, and then you can run any command through Tor in such fashion: `tsocks nslookup yahoo.com`

On Windows a neat program that is this equivalent is ProxyCap but it isn't free.

As far as browsing Web pages you certainly want to chain it through Polipo or Privoxy to strip your outgoing HTTP requests of potentially identifying information before Tor gets it.

Answer (score 3):

You can can run [Tor through a Polipo proxy](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/tor.html), and then use that proxy with your application.  I do this on a Debian machine and it works fine with cURL.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is install Tor:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install tor
```

Then just use torsocks by putting "torsocks" followed by the name of the app.
Example:

```
torsocks lynx ip4.me
```

That's it. I don't know why I had to search so hard to find that.

---

To check Tor status run:

```
systemctl status tor
```

To restart Tor run:

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

If you compare the IP you get with:

```
torsocks lynx ip4.me
```

and:

```
lynx ip4.me
```

You can verify that the IP is different and so it is using Tor.